# Не обновляется python 3.11 через Homebrew

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, macos, mac

```
    Last login: Sat Oct 29 17:48:34 on ttys000
 ~ % xcode-select --install
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
 ~ % brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly! Run:
  rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"
  brew tap homebrew/core

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3.11-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3.10-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3-config

Warning: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this old version.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from MacHomebrew on Twitter.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.


Warning: Some taps are not on the default git origin branch and may not receive
updates. If this is a surprise to you, check out the default branch with:
  git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master

Warning: Homebrew's "sbin" was not found in your PATH but you have installed
formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
 ~ % brew install python3
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
Warning: No available formula with the name "python3".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
It was migrated from homebrew/cask to homebrew/core.
```

Версия системы: macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H15) Версия Kernel: Darwin 19.6.0

Homebrew был успешно установлен через терминал, по ссылке с офф сайта, а дальше пошли танцы с бубном. С офф сайта python 3.11 ставиться. Идея такова, хотелось бы обновить уже имеющийся python в системе macOS, а не скачивать каждый раз с [www.python.org/downloads/](https://www.python.org/downloads/) снося старую версию.

```
 ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня тоже после установки произошла такая проблема.Скоре всего, у вас устаревшая версия mac как и у меня.Тем самым, Apple и Homebrew не поддерживает эту версию.К сожалению, с этим ничего нельзя поделать.